# Wrap a String until a given String - PHP

Tags: php

I have the following strings:

> - ST->place
> - ST->site->Room A->Freezer 1
> - ST->something->Room B->Freezer 2->JenLocation
> - ST->Building->Room C->Freezer 3->Rack 1->Shelf

I need to wrap the string if it's length is more than 10.If it does,I want to wrap it from the 11th character,until the last appearance  of the "->" string.And add between this wrapping "~~".So the output should be:

> - ST->place
> - ST->site~~->Freezer 1
> - ST->some~~~->JenLocation
> - ST->Buil~~~->Shelf

I have the code which wraps from the 11th caracher.But I manage to wrap from the end only a given number of characters(in this example,5)...not until last appearance of "->".

Here is my code:

```
             if(strlen($string)>10){

                    $a = explode(PHP_EOL,wordwrap($string, 11, PHP_EOL, true), 2);
                    $b = explode(PHP_EOL, wordwrap(strrev($string), 5, PHP_EOL, true), 2);
                    $shortString= $a[0] . ' ~~~ ' . strrev($b[0]);       

                    $arName[] = $shortString;
```

So how to wrap a string until last appearance of `->`? Or,if you use my code, **until the first apeparance of it (`$b` uses `strrev`).**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// find the last '->'
$pos = strrpos($string, '->');

// if found and is far enough, wrap the string
if ($pos !== FALSE && $pos > 15)
    $result = substr($string, 0, 11).' ~~ '.substr($string, $pos);
```

Comment: It's just a typo, sorry, I'll fix it.

Comment: I am not sure about the 11 and 15 constants, You adjust them for Your needs, I guess their meaning is obvious. Feel free to accept my answer, if it is ok for You :-)